# Как сделать обновление в таблице с помощью триггера SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Как сделать обновление в таблице с помощью триггера SQL?
Я обновляю таблицу  **test_trigger** , в которой есть триггер для обновления таблицы **table_forum**. Но я не могу понять как можно обновлять **table_forum** если какие то данные изменились в **test_trigger**. Как можно передать значение в триггер **1000** и **200**, которые я передаю в таблицу **test_trigger**?

Обновляем **test_trigger**:

```
UPDATE test_trigger SET test_name=1000  WHERE  test_name=200;
```

Вот триггер таблицы **test_trigger**:

```
BEGIN
SET foreign_key_checks =  0 ; 
  UPDATE  table_forum  
  SET  forum2=как тут передать значение 1000 из UPDATE?  
  WHERE  forum2=как тут передать значение 200 из UPDATE?;
SET foreign_key_checks =  1 ;
END
```

Примечание: Триггер с параметром AFTER. То есть, сначала таблица обновляется **test_trigger**  а потому же **table_forum**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо использовать alias `NEW` и `OLD`.
`OLD` -  это запись до изменения
`NEW` -  это запись после изменения

Т.е. в Вашем варианте будет так:

```
BEGIN
SET foreign_key_checks =  0 ; 
 UPDATE table_forum  SET forum2=NEW.test_name WHERE forum2=OLD.test_name
SET foreign_key_checks =  1 ;
END
```

Это можно использовать как в триггерах **BEFORE UPDATE**, так и в **AFTER UPDATE**

Comment: Это работает если триггер с значением  BEFORE UPDATE, но если будет значение AFTER UPDATE, почему то не работает( А как сделать что бы именно с AFTER работало?

Comment: Получается если с AFTER , то сначала обновляется test_trigger, а потом OLD и NEW, теоретически, приобретают единое новое значение, из-за этого в table_forum не находит такую запись, которой там и не было.

Comment: @semiromid, спасибо... добавил в ответ.

Comment: cyadvert Хех, это Вам спасибо) Я то всего лишь спрашивал)

Comment: @semiromid, поправка. Порылся в доках. Оказывается `NEW<>OLD` можно использовать в обоих вариантах `UPDATE` триггера. Система достаточно умна, чтобы помнить `OLD`. Там другие ограничения: `OLD` не существует в `INSERT` триггерах, а `NEW` не существует в триггерах `DELETE`.

Comment: cyadvert очень странно, потому что у меня триггер   с BEFORE UPDATE - работает,  а  с AFTER UPDATE - не работает ,пишет что не находит запись в таблице table_forum.

Comment: @semiromid, но я проверил: `In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.` вот тут http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: cyadvert - OLD.col_name - можно использовать до того как будет обновлен.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33102/discussion-between-cyadvert-and-semiromid).